# Putting 2 input text boxes next to each other

Tags: html, css

I found the following form online with css and am trying to modify it to be able to put 2 input boxes next to each other. I modified the code very slightly and it goes next to each other but they look unaligned and i can't figure out how to get that part fixed. Any help is very much appreciated. I have also attached an image to show what it looks like when i run the code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPB27.png)

```css
.form-style-5 {
  max-width: 900px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.form-style-5 fieldset {
  border: none;
}

.form-style-5 legend {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-style-5 label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.form-style-5 input[type="text"],
.form-style-5 input[type="date"],
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"],
.form-style-5 input[type="email"],
.form-style-5 input[type="number"],
.form-style-5 input[type="search"],
.form-style-5 input[type="time"],
.form-style-5 input[type="url"],
.form-style-5 textarea,
.form-style-5 select {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: #8a97a0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.form-style-5 input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="date"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="email"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="number"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="search"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="time"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="url"]:focus,
.form-style-5 textarea:focus,
.form-style-5 select:focus {
  background: #d2d9dd;
}

.form-style-5 select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
  height: 35px;
}

.form-style-5 .number {
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.form-style-5 input[type="submit"],
.form-style-5 input[type="button"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 19px 39px 18px 39px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #1abc9c;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #16a085;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-style-5 input[type="submit"]:hover,
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]:hover {
  background: #109177;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-style-5">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend><span class="number">1</span>Contact Info</legend>
      <input style="float:left;" type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Your Name *">
      <input style="float:right;" type="email" name="field2" placeholder="Your Email *">
      <textarea name="field3" placeholder="About yourself"></textarea>
      <label for="job">Interests:</label>
      <select id="job" name="field4">
<optgroup label="Indoors">
  <option value="fishkeeping">Fishkeeping</option>
  <option value="reading">Reading</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: it's hard to say since there's so much going on. try deconstructing it. use codepen.com or jsfiddle.com and start removing things one-by-one!

Comment: I changed your question to use a snippet instead of just the code, something a little more interactive, and i don't see the problem you describe, the inputs are aligned.

Comment: I see that it is working just saving it to an html file, i am adding this to a wordpress page and i'm pretty sure that wordpress is the culprit, no idea though how to even go about fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/x6so1m74/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <label>Field 1</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Field 2</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}

div label {
    display: block;
}
```

You should be able to do the same thing with your own code by using this example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine in other contexts.

Check out this [CODEPEN.](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/XYOKOz)

It also works fine in the code snippet below.

How were you viewing the page while taking the screenshot? That is likely the culprit, not the code!

```css
.form-style-5{
    max-width: 900px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.form-style-5 fieldset{
    border: none;
}
.form-style-5 legend {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-style-5 label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"],
.form-style-5 input[type="date"],
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"],
.form-style-5 input[type="email"],
.form-style-5 input[type="number"],
.form-style-5 input[type="search"],
.form-style-5 input[type="time"],
.form-style-5 input[type="url"],
.form-style-5 textarea,
.form-style-5 select {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    background-color: #e8eeef;
    color:#8a97a0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="date"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="email"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="number"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="search"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="time"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="url"]:focus,
.form-style-5 textarea:focus,
.form-style-5 select:focus{
    background: #d2d9dd;
}
.form-style-5 select{
    -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
    height:35px;
}
.form-style-5 .number {
    background: #1abc9c;
    color: #fff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 4px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.form-style-5 input[type="submit"],
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 19px 39px 18px 39px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #1abc9c;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: normal;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #16a085;
    border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"]:hover,
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]:hover
{
    background: #109177;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-style-5">
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend><span class="number">1</span>Contact Info</legend>
<input style="float:left;" type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Your Name *">
<input style="float:right;" type="email" name="field2" placeholder="Your Email *">
<textarea name="field3" placeholder="About yourself"></textarea>
<label for="job">Interests:</label>
<select id="job" name="field4">
<optgroup label="Indoors">
  <option value="fishkeeping">Fishkeeping</option>
  <option value="reading">Reading</option>
</optgroup>
</select>      
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Apply" />
</form>
</div>
```